# Comunicação socket Java e Python

Tags: java, android, python, socket

Estou realizando um trabalho acadêmico onde estou desenvolvendo um app Android que controla uma simulação de robô feita em Python. Estou tentando fazer a comunicação através de um socket onde ao pressionar uma tecla no app é enviado o comando de uma certa letra para que o robô se movimente. Usei como base alguns exemplos encontrados aqui, mas acredito que não apliquei-os corretamente visto que o app (client) não está se conectando com a aplicação em python (server), gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado.

Edit: Atualizando o código com o que foi sugerido no comentário, agora ao pressionar um botão com o evento, o app crasha. O código da clase CommSocket e da aplicação em Python estão atualizados. Adicionei também um trecho de log que coletei do celular no momento em que a aplicação crasha.
Melhorando o entendimento da situação, o teste é feito em um celular e a aplicação em python roda em um computador, ambos conectados na mesma rede.

Código da aplicação em Python:

```
import socket
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
import sys, select, os
if os.name == 'nt':
  import msvcrt
else:
  import tty, termios

if __name__=="__main__":

    HOST = '198.162.0.10'  # Endereco IP do Servidor
    PORT = 6789            # Porta que o Servidor esta
    queue = 5
    bufferSize = 256
    tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    orig = (HOST, PORT)
    tcp.bind(orig)
    tcp.listen(queue)

    try:
        print(msg)
        while(1):
#            key = getKey()
            con, cliente = tcp.accept()
            print ('Concetado por', cliente)
            key = con.recv(bufferSize)
            if key == 'w' :
                target_linear_vel = checkLinearLimitVelocity(target_linear_vel + LIN_VEL_STEP_SIZE)
                status = status + 1
                print(vels(target_linear_vel,target_angular_vel))
            elif key == 'x' :
                target_linear_vel = checkLinearLimitVelocity(target_linear_vel - LIN_VEL_STEP_SIZE)
                status = status + 1
                print(vels(target_linear_vel,target_angular_vel))
            elif key == 'a' :
                target_angular_vel = checkAngularLimitVelocity(target_angular_vel + ANG_VEL_STEP_SIZE)
                status = status + 1
                print(vels(target_linear_vel,target_angular_vel))
            elif key == 'd' :
                target_angular_vel = checkAngularLimitVelocity(target_angular_vel - ANG_VEL_STEP_SIZE)
                status = status + 1
                print(vels(target_linear_vel,target_angular_vel))
            elif key == ' ' or key == 's' :
                target_linear_vel   = 0.0
                control_linear_vel  = 0.0
                target_angular_vel  = 0.0
                control_angular_vel = 0.0
                print(vels(target_linear_vel, target_angular_vel))
            else:
                if (key == '\x03'):
                    break
            con.close()
```

CommSocket.java

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CommSocket extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
    private static final String hostname = "localhost";
    private static final String addr = "198.162.0.10";
    private static final int portaServidor = 6789;
    private IAsyncHandler mHandler;

    public CommSocket(IAsyncHandler mHandler) {
        this.mHandler = mHandler;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(addr, portaServidor);
            //SocketAddress socket = new InetSocketAddress(addr, portaServidor);

            //dados enviados para o servidor
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

            //Estou usando Arrays.toString(), somente para ele pegar todas as strings que passar no
            //método.
            bw.write(Arrays.toString(params));
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();

            //dados recebidos pelo servidor
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String retorno =  "Dados cadastrados " + br.readLine(); //retornar ok
            socket.close();

            return retorno;
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        mHandler.postResult(result);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;

import com.example.tcc_wheelchair.CommSocket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IAsyncHandler{

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //CommSocket task = new CommSocket(MainActivity.this);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }
    
    public void eventClickStop (View view)
    {
        TextView texto = findViewById(R.id.textViewteste);
        texto.setText("STOP");

        CommSocket task = new CommSocket(MainActivity.this);
        task.doInBackground("s");
    }

    public void eventClickUp (View view)
    {
        TextView texto = findViewById(R.id.textViewteste);
        texto.setText("UP ARROW");

        CommSocket task = new CommSocket(MainActivity.this);
        task.doInBackground("w");
    }

    public void eventClickDown (View view)
    {
        TextView texto = findViewById(R.id.textViewteste);
        texto.setText("DOWN ARROW");

        CommSocket task = new CommSocket(MainActivity.this);
        task.doInBackground("x");
    }

    public void eventClickRight (View view)
    {
        TextView texto = findViewById(R.id.textViewteste);
        texto.setText("RIGHT ARROW");

        CommSocket task = new CommSocket(MainActivity.this);
        task.doInBackground("d");
    }

    public void eventClickLeft (View view)
    {
        TextView texto = findViewById(R.id.textViewteste);
        texto.setText("LEFT ARROW");

        CommSocket task = new CommSocket(MainActivity.this);
        task.doInBackground("a");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public void postResult(String result) {
        //Neste método você pega o resultado da asynctask e aproveita de alguma forma
    }
}

interface IAsyncHandler {
    void postResult(String result);
}
```

Log do celular:

```
--------- beginning of crash
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.tcc_wheelchair, PID: 9374
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6864)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 11 more
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1513)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:389)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:570)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:450)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.example.tcc_wheelchair.CommSocket.doInBackground(CommSocket.java:31)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.example.tcc_wheelchair.MainActivity.eventClickUp(MainActivity.java:112)
06-03 23:07:52.266  9374  9374 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 13 more
06-03 23:07:52.357  1682  2970 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.tcc_wheelchair/.MainActivity
06-03 23:07:52.378  1682  1849 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
06-03 23:07:52.378  1682  1849 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
06-03 23:07:52.382  1682  3467 D ActivityManager: report kill process: killerPid is:9374, killedPid is:9374
06-03 23:07:52.473  1682  2317 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{9e15302 u0 com.example.tcc_wheelchair/com.example.tcc_wheelchair.MainActivity}
06-03 23:07:52.474  1682  1776 I ActivityManager: Process com.example.tcc_wheelchair (pid 9374) has died: vis  TOP 
06-03 23:07:52.475  1682  1776 D ProcessManager: skip restart com.example.tcc_wheelchair because of low mem!
06-03 23:07:52.514  1682  1776 I Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:22000511
06-03 23:07:52.515  1682  1857 W ActivityManager: setHasOverlayUi called on unknown pid: 9374
06-03 23:07:52.522  1682  2448 I Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:22000519
06-03 23:07:52.537  1682  1929 V UiModeManager: switch night mode to 2
06-03 23:07:52.561  1682  1968 D ActivityManagerServiceInjector: Begin to report package foreground events...
06-03 23:07:52.564  1682  3467 I Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:22000560
06-03 23:07:52.576  1682  3467 I Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:22000572
06-03 23:07:52.621  1682  1929 V UiModeManager: switch night mode to 2
06-03 23:07:52.626  1682  3467 I Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:22000622
06-03 23:07:52.661  1682  1906 I Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:22000657
06-03 23:07:52.661  1682  1906 I Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_stopped time:22000657
06-03 23:07:52.668  1682  1857 I Timeline: Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{c776715 u0 com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer/com.android.fileexplorer.activity.FileCategoryActivity t23447} time:22000665
06-03 23:07:52.713  1682  2969 I ActivityManager: Killing 7563:com.android.vending:download_service/u0a42 (adj 906): empty #17
06-03 23:07:52.740  1682  2436 D ConnectivityService: ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=569, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Unwanted:  Uid: 10042] ], android.os.BinderProxy@9406917)
06-03 23:07:52.741  1682  1946 D ConnectivityService: releasing NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=569, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Unwanted:  Uid: 10042] ] (release request)
06-03 23:07:52.741  1682  2970 D ProcessManager: skip restart com.android.vending:download_service because of low mem!
06-03 23:07:53.080  1682  2970 I ActivityManager: Killing 7770:com.google.android.gms.unstable/u0a30 (adj 906): empty #17
06-03 23:07:53.153  1682  2448 D ProcessManager: skip restart com.google.android.gms.unstable because of low mem!
06-03 23:07:55.004  1682  2448 W BaseMiuiPhoneWindowManager: keyCode:3 down:true eventTime:22002999 downTime:22002999 policyFlags:2b000002 flags:48 deviceId:-1 isScreenOn:true keyguardActive:false repeatCount:0
06-03 23:07:55.167  1682  2448 W BaseMiuiPhoneWindowManager: keyCode:3 down:false eventTime:22003163 downTime:22002999 policyFlags:2b000002 flags:48 deviceId:-1 isScreenOn:true keyguardActive:false repeatCount:0
06-03 23:07:55.253  1682  1921 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.miui.home/.launcher.Launcher (has extras)} from uid 1000
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente isto:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(addr, portaServidor);
```

em vez disto:

```
 Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, portaServidor);
```

Se estiverem em máquinas diferentes (estou supondo que seu teste com o aplicativo Android ainda é no emulador na mesma máquina em que está o servidor) atribua o IP da máquina para addr no aplicativo e em HOST no script python do servidor. Tente usar o IP da rede local em vez de usar o localhost (ou 127.0.0.1) já que esses endereços não são acessíveis por outras máquinas na mesma rede. Também, ao testar o aplicativo em um aparelho celular lembre-se de conectar na mesma rede do servidor.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, com essas modificações ao clicar em algum botão correspondente às ações, o app crasha. O teste está sendo feito em um aparelho celular e o script rodando no PC, ambos conectados na mesma rede. Tem ideia do que possa ser?

Comment: Atualize a pergunta com o novo código e com qualquer mensagem de erro que você tenha acesso para poder ajudar melhor.

Comment: Olá Emerson, editei a pergunta e adicionei um log. Obrigado.

Comment: Nunca programei para android mas a documentação da AsyncTask ( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask ) diz que você não deve chamar o doInBackground diretamente, para que a execução realmente aconteça de forma assíncrona, você deve chamar o método execute da API passando os parâmetros. No seu código seria, por exemplo, assim `task.execute("w")` em vez de `task.doInBackground("w")`. Repare também que essa classe está obsoleta (@Deprecated) e que em futuras versões seu código pode deixar de funcionar.

Comment: Nesta resposta tem uma breve explicação de porquê seu código deu erro: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22395546/4712790